# Solving Optimization Problem (Orthogonal Projection) Using Projected Sub Gradient / Dual Projected Subgradient

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Given the following optimization problem (Orthogonal Projection):

$$
{\mathcal{P}}_{\mathcal{T}} \left( x \right) = \arg \min _{y \in \mathcal{T} } \left\{ \frac{1}{2} {\left\| x - y \right\|}^{2} \right\}
$$

Where $ \mathcal{T} = \left\{ x \mid {e}^{T} x = k, \; \forall i, \: 0 \leq {x}_{i} \leq 1 \right\} $ and $ \forall i, \,{e}_{i} = 1 $ and $k $ is known.

I tried solving it using [KKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) yet couldn't get into a solution.
I was able to solve it using [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/) yet I wanted a method I can see what happens.

1. Could anyone solve it using KKT?
2. How can solve it using iterated method? It seems to fit Projected Sub Gradient / Dual Projected Subgradient yet I couldn't calculate the items needed.

Thank You.

Comment: Section 3 of [this paper](https://stanford.edu/~jduchi/projects/DuchiShSiCh08.pdf) describes an approach using KKT conditions.

Comment: the real k si given ?

Comment: @Smilia, yes $ k $ is given.

Comment: @angryavian, The paper doesn't bound the elements from above. Thank You.

Comment: and $0\le x \le 1$ means $|x| \le 1$ or $\forall i, 0\le x_i\le 1$ ?

Comment: @Smilia, it means $ 0 \leq {x}_{i} \leq 1 $. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Community Wiki Solution, Feel free to edit and add.

I will point up and mark solution for any other solution made by the community.

## KKT

The Lagrangian is given by:

$$ L \left( y, \lambda \right) = \frac{1}{2} {\left\| y - x \right\|}^{2} + \mu \left( {e}^{T} y - k \right) - {\lambda}_{1}^{T} y + {\lambda}_{2}^{T} \left( y - e \right) $$

The KKT Constraints:

\begin{align}
\left( 1 \right) \; & {\nabla}_{y} L \left( y, \lambda \right) = y - x + \mu e - {\lambda}_{1} + {\lambda}_{2} & = 0 \\
\left( 2 \right) \; & {\nabla}_{\mu} L \left( y, \lambda \right) = {e}^{T} y - k & = 0 \\
\left( 3 \right) \; & -{\lambda}_{1}^{T} y & = 0 \\
\left( 4 \right) \; & {\lambda}_{2}^{T} \left( y - e \right) & = 0 \\
\left( 5 \right) \; & {\lambda}_{1} & \geq 0 \\
\left( 6 \right) \; & {\lambda}_{2} & \geq 0
\end{align}

Multiplying $ \left( 1 \right) $ by $ {e}^{T} $ and using $ \left( 2 \right) $ yields:

$$ {e}^{T} y - {e}^{T} x + \mu {e}^{T} e +{e}^{T} {\lambda}_{2} \Rightarrow \mu = \frac{ {e}^{T} x - k }{ n - {e}^{T} {\lambda}_{1} + {e}^{T} {\lambda}_{2} } $$

Plugging the result into $ \left( 1 \right) $ yields

Seems to be hard to get analytic solution.
Any other way to solve this system of equations?

Under Work...
Feel free to continue.

## Projected Subgradient

## Dual Projected Sub Gradient

Given a Problem in the form:

\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{x} & \quad f \left( x \right) \\
s.t. & \quad {g}_{i} \left( x \right) \leq 0 , \; i = 1, 2, \cdots, m \\
& \quad x \in \mathcal{S}
\end{align*}

Where

1. $ \mathcal{S} \in \mathbb{E} $ is Convex.
2. $ f : \mathbb{E} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is convex.
3. $ {g}_{i} : \mathbb{E} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is Convex.

Then, from [Amir Beck](https://web.iem.technion.ac.il/en/people/userprofile/becka.html)'s Lecture Notes, The Dual Projected Sub Gradient is given by:

- Pick $ {\lambda}^{0} \in {\mathbb{R}}_{+} $.
- For $ k = 0, 1, 2, \cdots $ Calculate:

  - $ {x}_{k} = \arg \min_{x \in \mathcal{S}} \left\{ f \left( x \right) + \sum_{i = 1}^{m} {\lambda}_{i}^{k} {g}_{i} \left( x \right) \right\} $.
  - $ {\lambda}_{i}^{k + 1} = {\left[ {\lambda}_{i}^{k} + {t}_{k} \frac{ {g}_{i} \left( {x}^{k} \right) }{ {\left\| {g}_{i} \left( {x}^{k} \right) \right\|}_{2} } \right]}_{+} $.

In this problem $ f \left( y \right) = \frac{1}{2} { \left\| y - x \right\| }^{2} $, $ i = 1, 2, ..., n, \; {g}_{i} \left( y \right) = -{y}_{i} $, $ i = n + 1, n + 2, ..., 2n, \; {g}_{i} \left( y \right) = {y}_{i} - 1 $ and $ \mathcal{S} = \left\{ x \mid {e}^{T} x = k \right\} $.

The Sub Problem $ {x}_{k} = \arg \min_{x \in \mathcal{S}} \left\{ f \left( x \right) + \sum_{i = 1}^{m} {\lambda}_{i}^{k} {g}_{i} \left( x \right) \right\} $ should be solved using Projected Sub Gradient.

In this case the Projection Operator is given by $ {\mathcal{P}}_{{e}^{T} x = k} \left( x \right) = x - e {\left( {e}^{T} e \right)}^{-1} \left( {e}^{T} x - b \right) $.
The Gradient of $ L \left( y, \lambda \right) = \frac{1}{2} { \left\| y - x \right\| }^{2} + \sum_{i = 1}^{m} {\lambda}_{i} {g}_{i} \left( x \right) $ is given by $ {\nabla}_{y} L \left( y, \lambda \right) = y - x + {\left[ \left( {\lambda}_{n + 1} - {\lambda}_{1} \right), \left( {\lambda}_{n + 2} - {\lambda}_{2} \right), \cdots, \left( {\lambda}_{2n} - {\lambda}_{n} \right) \right]}^{T} $.

This is a MATLAB code which implements the method:

```
function [ vY ] = ProjX( vX, numElmntsK )
%UNTITLED6 Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
 
numDim  = size(vX, 1);
vE      = ones([numDim, 1]);
 
hProjFunc   = @(vY) vY - (vE * ((vE.' * vE) \ ((vE.' * vY) - numElmntsK)));
hGFunc      = @(vY) [-vY; (vY - vE)];
hGradLFun   = @(vY, vLambda) vY - vX - vLambda(1:numDim) + vLambda((numDim + 1):(2 * numDim));
 
% numIterDual = 6000;
numIterProj = 150;
 
vY          = vE;
vY          = numElmntsK * (vY / sum(vY));
vLambda     = 0.5 * ones([(2 * numDim), 1]);
stepSize    = 0.0075;
 
minConstVal = inf;
 
minConstThr = 0.00005;
 
while(minConstVal > minConstThr)
    % Dual Projected Sub Gradient
    for jj = 1:numIterProj
        % Projetcted Sub Gradient
        vY = hProjFunc(vY - (stepSize * hGradLFun(vY, vLambda)));
    end
    vLambda = vLambda + (stepSize * hGFunc(vY) / norm(hGFunc(vY), 2));
    vLambda = max(vLambda, 0);
    
    minConstVal = abs(sum(vLambda .* hGFunc(vY)));
end
 
 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've worked this problem out before, and from what I remember, you should get from your optimality conditions that $y^*= \min(\max(x+\mu 1,0),1)$, where $\mu$ is chosen so that $1^Ty^* = k$. In words, to project onto the intersection of a box ($0\le y \le 1$) and a plane ($1^Ty = k$), move in the direction normal to the plane until the projection onto the box is on the plane.

This matlab code should do it.

```
function y = projboxplane(x,k)
    n = length(x);    
    breaks = [-x(:); 1-x(:)];
    [breaks,sigma] = sort(breaks);
    slope = cumsum((-1).^(sigma>n));
    f = cumsum([0;slope(1:end-1).*diff(breaks)]);
    ix = sum(f <= k);
    mu = breaks(k) + (k-f(ix))/slope(ix);
    y = min(max(x + mu,0),1);
```

The ideas in the Duchi et al. paper mentioned in the comments can also be applied to avoid the sort to get a linear time algorithm.

Comment: I will try it. I also solved it in the Dual Domain. I will update it later. Feel free to edit my answer if you want to add more rigorous math description.